# Is there a way to communicate between SOAP service and Rest API in .Net

Tags: .net, rest, soap

There is a client Mobile app that calls an existing SOAP Service , now we need to add Rest API (for other clients like Web,.... etc) without changing SOAP or Mobile App logic ,
is there a way to make SOAP Service calls the newly created Rest API ?

Comment: It's unclear: do you mean for the server's soap handler to call the REST API on the server (not sure why that would be beneficial) or for SOAP clients to be able to call the REST API (not possible, different protocols).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError , when a mobile app calls the soap web method i want the soap in return to call the Rest API for processing the request ,, so soap is like a bridge between client and Rest API .

Comment: That should work fine.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, and what is the way for implementing this approach ?